# Can you access 'Service Reference' Programmatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, envdte

Info: C#, Visual Studio 2010

I am trying to access the existing service references and am not sure how, I can achieve the following to get all 'references'

```
DTE2 test = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE2;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
VSProject2 project = test.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.ContainingProject.Object as VSProject2;

 foreach (Reference item in project.References)
 {
      sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Name: {0}", item.Name));
 }

 MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

project does have the property:

```
project.WebReferencesFolder
```

but it is null (yes, I do have a service reference added, honest)

Comment: I think I have found the interface called WebService - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vswebsite.webservices(VS.100).aspx still not completed my challenge yet though!

Comment: I feel like I am getting warmer.....
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vssdkwcftools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the 3rd Example from the MSDN Sample:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vssdkwcftools

```
IVsWCFReferenceManager referenceManager = refMgrFactory.GetReferenceManager(hierarchy);

 IVsWCFReferenceGroupCollection referenceGroups = referenceManager.GetReferenceGroupCollection();
```

The namespace I was after was **Microsoft.VisualStudio.WCFReference.Interop**
in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Beta2 SDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.WCFReference.Interop.dll